# Correcting the authors name on google scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar

I was wondering if anyone here may have had any success with getting title / author's details corrected on Google Scholar?

I have recently published an article and my surname was incorrectly parsed by Google Scholar. As you can see from my username my surname is hyphenated and Google parsed either first or the second part of it as a surname but never both.

I have tried contacting Google Scholar and could not get any human response from them.

Has anyone found/ heard of any way of fixing these bibliographic errors in Google?

Comment: By personal experience, Google Scholar ignores any comment you may make in on any mistake they made. On of my references is from the famous paper *"This content has been downloaded from IOPscience. Please scroll down to see the full text."*. Basically until Google decides to improve their algorithms, we need to live with their mistakes, unfortunately. This is the reason too that you need to double check any bibliographic reference obtained via Google

Comment: This is something you have to take up with Google Scholar, we do not operate or edit what they do....

Comment: @AnderBiguri - that paper sounds like it would make a great Broadway musical...

Comment: @SolarMike I have contacted Google Scholar on the 11th of March. I'm still waiting for the response but I thought someone on Stack Exchange may have a solution.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Feel your pain. Actually I found 41 different records with "your" title on Google Scholar. All from iopscience.iop.org . I think it would be good if GS had a feedback form.

Comment: @DanutaM.Lisiecka-Ford the solution is that there is no solution, unfortunately

Comment: I think you should be able to edit the article, as it appears on you profile page (perhaps not elsewhere), via the following steps. 1) Click on the article title in your publication list (https://i.imgur.com/HrFHVzM.png). 2) Click the pen icon in the top-right of the popup (https://i.imgur.com/InptVwf.png). 3) Make your changes and hit the tick button (https://i.imgur.com/roqpu9q.png). Please note: untested, YMMV. (https://imgur.com/a/g0cQd)

Comment: Why do you expect free (as in beer) services like Google Scholar to have the same levels of accuracy and completeness as Web of Science / Scopus? I find Scholar very useful, but I don't expect it to be perfect.

Comment: @WanderingChemist Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have already done it and I was wondering if this may be propagated to the search results in the main Google Search

Comment: @user_of_math We may need to agree to disagree on how each one perceives what perfection is. Besides, I see locating the solution to this problem as a challenge. In all seriousness though it is beyond the scope of this forum to be commenting on culture and politics which will follow if we start discussing what role content providers and advertisers play in massive free platforms and what it is to pay in digital era.