# How can a miscitation in google scholar be corrected?

Tags: authorship, google-scholar

I discovered that the journal article Ten Migrant Returnees Ilongos, Mindanao Vignettes and the Memory of Nation published by the Philippine Journal of Social Sciences and Humanities (PJSSH) which I authored is now authored by a certain H.V Banez. See Links below

http://pjssh.com.ph/index.php/PJSSH/article/view/169/72?fbclid=IwAR0Z0ZfdW9-StIjclUD7KRCvuICQr0BUmXug3aqsV0-NuC0Ge5ZWUFg-bGg

http://pjssh.com.ph/index.php/PJSSH/issue/view/30?fbclid=IwAR0HJ5sD0YPAI5CQXj3co3pLquyxX145-zMTd9CDUo9GKPYwg7RWjPcu6Yc

https://scholar.google.com.ph/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Ma+Arve+Banez&oq=

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/106764/64

Comment: We don’t run google - you need to contact them.